# Handling multiple users for each selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm using org.databene.benerator.anno.Source to handle my different user logins for each test. Example:

```
@Test
@Source("allUsers.csv")
@Category(Deep.class)
public void testRenameFunctionality(String user, String password){
    login(user, password);
    createPlan.createPlan();
    planDetails.createDestinationReport();
    checkRenameFunctionality();
}
```

The different users are located in the csv file (allUsers.csv) and runs through the test with each user that is in the file. This has worked fine until I tried to incorporate multi browser testing with saucelabs. Here is my base class that has my multi browser credentials:

```
private String platform;
private String browserName;
private String browserVersion;

public BaseTest(String platform, String browserName, String browserVersion){
    super();
    this.browserName = browserName;
    this.browserVersion = browserVersion;
    this.platform = platform;
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static LinkedList data() throws Exception{
    LinkedList browsers = new LinkedList();

    if(host.equals("saucelabs")){
        browsers.add(new String[] {"firefox", "42", "Windows 7"});
        browsers.add(new String[] {"chrome", "46", "Windows 7"});
        browsers.add(new String[] {"internet explorer", "11", "Windows 7"});
    }else if(host.equals("localhost")){
        browsers.add(new String[] {"", "", ""});
    }

    return browsers;
}

//Rule for the before and after annotations.
@Rule
public ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        if(host.equals("saucelabs")){
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browserName);
            capabilities.setCapability("version", browserVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability("platform", platform);
            capabilities.setCapability("name", testName);
            capabilities.setCapability("resolution","1280x1024");
            String sauceUrl = String.format("http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub",
                    sauceUser, sauceKey);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(sauceUrl), capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();
            sauceClient = new SauceREST(sauceUser, sauceKey);
        }else if(host.equals("localhost")){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void after(){
        driver.quit();
    }
};
```

I'm also extending the BaseTest in my other test classes:

```
public class NavAppsTest extends BaseTest implements Config {

NavAppObject selectApp;

public NavAppsTest(String platform, String browserName, String browserVersion) {
    super(platform, browserName, browserVersion);
}
```

This works fine for test classes that don't have parameters but I get this initializationError when trying to run the tests with parameters:

```
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:171)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.databene.feed4junit.Feeder.<init>(Feeder.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
```

Each test class is extending my BaseTest so they all have a constructor that is getting the browser/OS info. I think the best way to go about this is to figure out a different way to handle each of the users that handle each test case. Any thoughts? Thanks!

-Bryan

Comment: What junit test runner are you using?  Your parameters method returns a linkedlist but your constructor arguments are three strings?  Also where is host defined? The exception appears to be thrown because your BaseTest class has a constructor with arguments.

Comment: I'm using junit 4.12. The host is defined in an interface. Right now it is set to localhost since I'm just trying to run it on my current machine.

Comment: Are you annotating the test class using parameters with `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`?  How is the constructor being passed the three strings? Your parameter is a linkedlist.

Comment: Updated above with how I'm passing the constructor. I am using @RunWith(Parameterized.class) in my BaseTest class which I'm extending to my other test classes.

Comment: I think its because I'm using 2 @RunWiths. I have a @RunWith(Feeder.class) for my test classes that are using the org.databene.benerator.anno.Source. I also have the @RunWith(Parameterized.class) for my BaseTest which im extending in each of my test classes.